# 英語が残っている: ヘルプ「Markdown または HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定する方法は?」の「画像」の説明

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

ヘルプ「Markdown または HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定する方法は?」の「画像」の説明に英語が残っている（"through us - even"）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

翻訳案は以下。

画像は編集者ツールバーのボタン「画像ボタン」を使用することで追加できます。ボタンを押すと画像アップロード用の画面が表示されるので、画像をアップロードして下さい（imgurホスティングサービスを経由します）また、クリップボードからのアップロードも可能です。更に、リンクの追加と同様に画像を入力することもできます。

Answer (score 1):

HTMLで編集する必要があるため、とりあえずHTMLコードをここに張ります。

調整する余裕の時には適用します。

```
<h2>画像</h2> <p>画像は主に編集者ツールバー ボタン<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3zkF.png" alt="画像の挿入ツールバー ボタン" />を使用することで追加できます。これにより、特殊なインターフェースが表示され、画像をオンラインで (imgur ホスティング サービス経由で)through us - even クリップボードからアップロードできます。または、リンクの追加と同様に入力することもできます。</p> <ul> <li>HTML <code>&lt;img src="http://example.com/img.jpg"&gt;</code></li> <li>Markdown <code>![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)</code></li> </ul>
```

### 画像

画像は主に編集者ツールバー ボタン[image: 画像の挿入ツールバー ボタン]を使用することで追加できます。これにより、特殊なインターフェースが表示され、画像をオンラインで (imgur ホスティング サービス経由で)through us - even クリップボードからアップロードできます。または、リンクの追加と同様に入力することもできます。

- HTML `<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">`
- Markdown

Comment: 本件ですが、まだ"through us - even"という不要な英語が残っています。単にこの英語を削除するだけでOKだと思います。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting